# SQL Server 2019 "Invalid object name sys.sysrowsets"

Tags: sql-server

I get folowing error: SQL Server 2019 "Invalid object name sys.sysrowsets", then I tried to select data from sys.sysrowsets table.
I have sql server 2019.
Do you know how solve this?
Thank you

Comment: This is why using *undocumented* system objects is a poor idea; they can change or even be removed and the documentation and release notes will not inform you. The fact that the *name* starts with `sys` (I'm not talking about the schema) likely means it was more of a compatibility view from SQL Server 2000 and was actually `dbo.sysrowsets`.

Comment: Looking at [What is the usage of sys.sysrowsets in SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118960/what-is-the-usage-of-sys-sysrowsets-in-sql-server), it looks like the information you want is likely in `sys.partitions`.

Comment: As a side note, I can't even see `sysrowsets` (on the `sys` or `dbo` schemas) in an old 2012 instance I still have kicking around, so I suspect that the object was removed some time ago.

Comment: Blargh, that question on [dba.se] was also posted (all around the same time) on at least 3 other sites... I ***hate*** it when people do that. If you care: [1](https://forums.sqlteam.com/t/what-is-the-usage-of-sys-sysrowsets/3773), [2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a4df4e94-a0fd-42d2-8f01-b79979df2c77/what-is-the-usage-of-syssysrowsets?forum=sqldatabaseengine), [3](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/what-is-the-usage-of-sys-sysrowsets)

Comment: @Larnu, I don't care of usage this table! I have a software that connects to sql server, and this software returns this error when it tries to select tables information!

Comment: Then fix the software, or report the bug to the software vendor.

Comment: @Larnu I don't have permissions or access to do it

Comment: Then you need to speak to someone that does. The object has, apparently, been removed from SQL Server and so you *cannot* access it. If you previously used the software on a legacy version of SQL Server, you might need to migrate back to that 2005(?) instance while you find a replacement product to the legacy application you are using, that doesn't support "recent" versions of SQL Server

Comment: @Larnu - I *think* these system base tables have always been gated behind the DAC since the concept of DAC existed. So either the software has been given a DAC connection string or was running against something even older

Comment: Huh, you learn something new every day, @MartinSmith .

Answer (score 2):

This is a [system base table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/system-base-tables?view=sql-server-ver16).

It still exists in SQL Server 2019

> Exists in every database. Contains a row for each partition rowset for
> an index or a heap.

It can be seen in the execution plan when selecting from sys.partitions but (as the docs explain)

> To bind to a system base table, a user must connect to the instance of
> SQL Server by using the dedicated administrator connection (DAC).
> Trying to execute a SELECT query from a system base table without
> connecting by using DAC raises an error.

So if you have appropriate permissions then technically the software can run the `SELECT` by connecting to the DAC port.

It is not advisable to do this though. Having software that routinely connects via the DAC rather than use documented views is not a good idea and is explicitly warned against in the docs

> Important
>
> Access to system base tables by using DAC is designed only for
> Microsoft personnel, and it is not a supported customer scenario.

What is this software doing for you? Why is it accessing base tables directly rather than using documented interfaces?

Comment: thank you, I enabled DAC, but it did not work for me. User has super priviliges and I enabled DAC by this tutorial by SSMS: https://www.mytechmantra.com/sql-server/different-ways-to-enable-dedicated-administrator-connection-in-sql-server/ . And I performed sp_configure 'remote admin connections', 1 
After restart the server..